# Special character replace with space

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, url, connection-string

I am passing variables true the url and the white space are replace with "+" or "%20" automatically by browser. After redirect page I want to split this word correctly.

ex:-http://localhost:8008/Login.aspx?stid=Are You Happy

after load login page this automatically convert,

http://localhost:8008/Login.aspx?stid=Are+You+Happy

or

http://localhost:8008/Login.aspx?stid=Are%20You%20Happy

How do I get this stid variable after load the page,

Are You Happy

Is there a way to do that using javascript or jquery??

And i want the same result when i send my parameter,

http://localhost:8008/Login.aspx?stid=Are+You+Happy

i want the result that should like following also.

Are+You+Happy

Can this both function done by javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 4):

```
//decode function
function decode(encodedStr) {
    return decodeURIComponent(encodedStr.replace(/\+/g,  " "));
}
```

---

```
//encode function
function encode(unencoded ) {
    return encodeURIComponent(unencoded).replace(/'/g,"%27").replace(/"/g,"%22");   
}
```

---

You can also use the [JQuery.params()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/):

```
var myObject = {
    stid: 'You are happy',
    b: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    .......
};
var recursiveEncoded = $.param( myObject );
var recursiveDecoded = decodeURIComponent( $.param( myObject ) );

alert( recursiveEncoded );
alert( recursiveDecoded );
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```js
var url = "http://localhost:8008/Login.aspx?stid=Are%20You%20Happy",
    decoded_url = decodeURIComponent(url.replace(/\+/g,  " "));  
    
alert(decoded_url.split('stid=')[1]);
```

Comment: Is jQuery really needed for this?

Comment: No, not at all. I removed jquery from the snippet.